# Xcode 9.4.1 - How to skip remainder of set and move to the next set

Tags: swift, for-loop, set

While this may not be a good example, but as the question states, I wish to compare `randomNo` to the sets within `numberSets`. However, the moment one number is found I want to know if there is a way to skip to the next set.

In summary `randomNo` contains 2 numbers which can be found in the same set these are "6" and "9". I want to know if the moment I find "6" and can void the rest of the set and move onto the next set without cycling through the rest of the numbers in the set

```
init() {
    let numberSet1 : Set<Int> = [1,2,3,4,5]
    let numberSet2 : Set<Int> = [6,7,8,9,10]
    let numberSet3 : Set<Int> = [11,12,13,14,15]

    let randomNo = [3,6,9,11]

    numberSets = [numberSet1,numberSet2,numberSet3]
}

func searchFor(){
    for num in randomNo{
        for set in numberSets{
            if set.contains(num) {
                print("The following number was found: ", num)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not use `break`? See [Control Transfer Statements](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/ControlFlow.html#ID135) in the Swift book.

Comment: The solution in my answer to your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53650907/xcode-9-4-1-swift-4-comparing-a-non-primitive-set-to-a-primitive-set-containin) considers this request, too.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to `continue` the outer loop:

```
outer: for num in randomNo{
    for set in numberSets{
        if set.contains(num) {
            print("The following number was found: ", num)
            continue outer
        }
    }
}
```

Another way is to union all three sets:

```
let union = numberSet1.union(numberSet2).union(numberSet3)

print(randomNo.filter(union.contains))
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I think it worth to mention that, in your example the code is not cycling through the sets, rather than arrays of sets (`randomNo`, `numberSets`).

If I get the problem right, you do not need to optimize looking up for element in set. Asking whether set contains element or not (a lookup), is not an expensive operation and has complexity of `O(1)`.

If want to stop iterating through the `numberSets` once first number is found, just use `break` control flow statement:

```
func searchFor() {
    for num in randomNo {
        for set in numberSets {
            if set.contains(num) {
                print("The following number was found: ", num)
                break
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.